# Display item in ngFor with some delay in Angular 5

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a scenario in which I have an array that filled at the run-time, I want to show its elements in HTML template via ngFor loop with some delay. (i.e display first item, then after some delay second item and so on.

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let x of array">{{x.name}}</li>
</ul>

this.selectedArray = [];
getArrayValues(index) {

this.Array2.forEach(e => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.selectedArray.push(e);
  }, 1000);
 })
}
```

I need every li to be generated after some delay.

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: Chellappan, I have added my code.

Comment: @AhmerKhan I hope this is a joke ... Add **what you have tried**, not that ...

Comment: Anyway, about your request, consider either pushing items one by one, or using angular animations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getArrayValues(0);
  }

  getArrayValues(index) {
    setInterval(() => {
      if(index == this.Array2.length)
        return;
      this.selectedArray.push(this.Array2[index]);
      index++;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mevzx8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Nice, way easy.... couldn't think of this. Don't know why but I ould rather use `clearInnterval()` and then return..

Comment: This works.. but since its appending to the array, it renders the for in a loop and flashes my whole screen, also each ngfor creates modules for me that do api calls.. this might not work for me haha

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of [animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations#delay) available implemented by `Angular` which can be applied to `ngFor`

You can see the demo direct:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-animations?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

For example, an animation `ease-in`

**Component**

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.2s ease-in')
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate('0.2s 0.1s ease-out', style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      }))
    ])
  ])
]
```

then, in HTML

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let x of array" [@flyInOut]="'in'">{{x.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I could only think of this solution, create a tempArray which populates in every second interval. I have written a recursive function which calls itself after every one second, the base condition is to check if the looping index is greater than or equal to the actual array length

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let x of tempArray">{{x.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
 arr = [1,2,3];

 tempArr = []


 function delayMe(index, tempArr) { 
  if (index >= arr.length) {
   return;
  }
    (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))).then(() => {
      tempArr.push(arr[index]);
      console.log(tempArr);
      delayMe(index + 1, tempArr)
    })

 }

 delayMe(0, tempArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change setTimeout for `setInterval` and add `this.Array2.pop()` to get new value after some time

```
  setInterval(() => {
    this.selectedArray.push(this.Array2.pop());
  }, 1000);
```